# Changing the name of major to aliasName

Tags: c#

everyone, I am trying to write code  that checks if there is alias name show it and if there is not then show the full name

This is my data:

[image]

This is My Code for showing FullName:

```
var TopStudents = await GetTopStudentsFromDb(count);
var codes = TopStudents.Select(e => e.StudentCode).Distinct().ToList();
var Students = await GetStudeentByCode(codes);

foreach (var St in TopStudents)
{
   St.StudentsName = 
       Students.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Code == St.StudentCode)?.NameMajor.Refine();
}
```

this code works and shows the name now I want to change it to show the alias name of the major what should I do?
I want to check if it has Alias name show it if it doesn't then show the name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best will be to add a property on you `TopStudens` type that uses the null null-coalescing operator ?? - like:

```
public class TopStudents {

  [NotMapped] // not persisted in database.
  public string AliasOrNameMajor => Alias ?? NameMajor;
}
```

and then do it this way:

```
foreach (var St in TopStudents)
{
   St.StudentsName = 
       Students.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Code == St.StudentCode)?.AliasOrNameMajor;
}
```

Comment: top students' result is from a query that takes the top 5 records I do not think I can do that i want to check and see if it is null or not.

Comment: What is the goal of this exercise - It is a bit confusing that you are mixing collections `TopStudents` and `Students`? Btw first letter in an variable should be lowerCase.